# Guessing Game - JButton doClick not working?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

I am trying to give the option for when if the game is won or lost it asks the user if they would like to play again. If yes the doClick funtion should click the restart button and restart the game but this is not working?

```
                if (GuessNumber == theNumber) {
                    statusLabel.setText("Winner! Guess is correct.");
                    statusLabel.setForeground(Color.green);
                    guessTF.setEditable(false);
                    guessTF.setBackground(Color.green);
                    int newGame = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Winner! Congratulations you have won."
                            + "\nYou guessed " +theNumber
                            + "\nWould you like to play again?" , "Guessing Game", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                    if(newGame == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                    {
                        newGameButton.doClick();
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        int no = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure you want to quit Guessing Game?", "Guessing Game", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
             if(no == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
            {
            System.exit(0);
            }
                    }
                }

                if (maxAttempt == 10 && GuessNumber != theNumber) {
                    statusLabel.setText("Game Over. You have exceeded your guessing limit.");
                    statusLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
                    guessTF.setEditable(false);
                    guessTF.setBackground(Color.red);
                    int gameNew = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Game over.\n The guessing limit has been exceeded :("
                            + "\nThe number was: " +theNumber
                            + "\nWould you like to play again?" , "Guessing Game", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                    if(gameNew == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                    {
                        newGameButton.doClick();
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        int no = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure you want to quit Guessing Game?", "Guessing Game", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
             if(no == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
            {
            System.exit(0);
            }
                    }
                }


            }
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 3) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! Most IDEs have a keyboard shortcut specifically for formatting code.